# Weblog Module for Sitecore 8.2 initial release

Tags: weblog

I have recently upgraded to Sitecore 8.2 initial release from Sitecore 8.1 Update 2. I was looking for an upgrade for the Weblog module for sitecore 8.2 as there are lots of changes happened and the weblog doesn't work anymore. Any idea if there is an upgrade or a new weblog module i can use.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latest released version was **WeBlog 2.4** which supports **Sitecore 7.0, 7.2, 7.5, 8.0**

Versions for **8.1** and **8.2** were not released yet,

Once we release it you will find packages here:

- **Marketplace:**
  https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/W/WeBlog.aspx?sc_lang=en
- **Github repository:**
  https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/releases

We are currently testing release packages and everything looks promising.
We need to close all these [issues](https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+milestone%3A%22release+3.0%22) before the release.

Cannot say anything more regarding ETA.

Our plan is to support every version starting from Sitecore **7.2**.

Some packages might appear earlier than the other.
The highest priority have versions **8.1** and **8.2**

Comment: Alright thank you, will be waiting for the release.

Comment: Hello.. any news on this? Thanks!

Comment: There is only one thing we are currently working on.

Comment: Which version are you working on? Do you think you would be done by the end of the year?

Comment: Yes. We would like to release it this week. First we are going to release packages for 8.0-8.2 version/

Comment: FYI **WeBlog 3.0** released https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/releases/tag/release%2F3.0

Comment: Thank you soo much.. I just downloaded the 3.0 version for 8.2  and unzipped it, but it is saying that the archive is corrupt, is that ok?

Comment: I have another question.. the following new feature (New SPEAK based WordPress import application).. Does that mean I can import the entries  from Weblog to Wordpress or the other way around? Because I might have to export the data from Weblog to Wordpress... Thanks

Comment: Wordpress-to-WeBlog only

Comment: Alright thanks.. and what about the archive being corrupted?I just downloaded the 3.0 version for 8.2 and unzipped it, but it is saying that the archive is corrupt, is that ok?

Comment: If you've got any other specific question raise them in the github or create a separate question here on stack. Packages are fine. I don't know why you unzip it. It is a standard Sitecore package.

Comment: Because if I install it, it will overwrite all blog entries I have :) so I want to take only the files and dlls

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's getting worked on, but no release date has been announced as far as I know.

The module is open source (https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog) so you could fork the project and fix the issues/bugs when running on Sitecore 8.2 to get you by for now. I would at least file bugs for issues you have run into so they can be tracked.